# -moz-user-focus equivalent for Chrome

Tags: javascript, css

I have a custom model dialog control that is used for any popups in our web pages.  When this dialog is initialized, the rest of the page is grayed out using jquery expose . I am adding the following styles to the mask div to prevent selection on the grayed out area.

```
  -moz-user-focus: ignore;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
```

On the dialog, pressing ‘esc’key closes the dialog and pressing ‘enter’ key works like clicking on ok or yes button. But if the user clicks anywhere on the grayed out area; the above css prevents focus from going onto any control in the grayed out area in firefox. For IE,I am programatically handling as follows

```
  $('#exposeMask').attr("contenteditable", "false");
  $('#exposeMask').attr("unselectable", "on");
```

But for Chrome, the above css -webkit-user-select prevents selection but does not help prevent focus.

I tried google to find a solution but I count not find any helpful links. Is there some style element equivalent to  -moz-user-focus for chrome?

Thanks in advance,
M

Comment: What about Opera and Konqueror?

Comment: I found a work around to fix this. Onclick of mask I am reseting focus back to dialog. Works fine in Chrome,Safari,IE, Firefox

Answer (score -3):

```
pointer-events: none;
```

That should do it.

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` has no affect on focusing an element through tabbing.